# SOLVED - How to override email/items.phtml?

Tags: magento2, layout, email, email-templates

I want to customize the email template and add some more columns.
For now I found out that the "email/items.phtml" seems to be the right file.
In the "sales_email_order_items.xml" are all necessary files. So I tried to override them but the only file I can change is the "email/items/order/default.phtml".
This is current progress:
 1. create the "sales_email_order_items.xml" in my module
 2. override the default.phtml

```
    <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

That works for the order items but I can't get to override the table head from "email/items.phtml".

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer instead of editing it in the question, so that the question does not count as unanswered. You also can mark your own answer as accepted after two days.

Answer (score 2):

*As yourself said editing the question, I'll just paste here the solution you (Tipo) found:*

Found the solution:
I tried all the time to change the template in this way:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="items">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" template="Vendor_Company::email/items.phtml"/>
```

Instead of using this:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Company::email/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
```